# failed to open stream: No such file or directory ,permission issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, upload

I just starting upload file with the script in my localhost,

but every time I want to upload file I giving an error:

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/upload.php on line 5

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/upload.php on line 6

I guess the problem with permission and path but I don't know how to solve it,
my code:

```
    <?php

define("UPLOAD_DIR",realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/uploads' );
    // set proper permissions on the new file
    chmod(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/uploads', 0777);
    chmod(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/uploads/'.$name, 0777);


if (!empty($_FILES["myFile"])) {
    $myFile = $_FILES["myFile"];

    if ($myFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo "<p>An error occurred.</p>";
        exit;
    }

    // ensure a safe filename
    $name = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9._-]/i", "_", $myFile["name"]);

    // don't overwrite an existing file
    $i = 0;
    $parts = pathinfo($name);
    while (file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $name)) {
        $i++;
        $name = $parts["filename"] . "-" . $i . "." . $parts["extension"];
    }

    // preserve file from temporary directory
    $success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"],
        UPLOAD_DIR . $name);
    if (!$success) { 
        echo "<p>Unable to save file.</p>";
        exit;
    }



}
?>
```

Comment: Set the permissions at the beginning of your code. And you have to use 0777, not only 777.

Comment: i edit the code now i giving another error,check the post above please,

Comment: Specify the complete path, not only "/uploads/". The answer below seems to be correct.

Comment: the code below is work, but now i see: "Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory" please check the first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chmod(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/uploads', 0777);

chmod(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/uploads/'.$name, 0777);
```

Comment: this code work but now i just give this error:
Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/upload.php on line 5

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/upload.php on line 6